# Record audio from two microphone and video from one webcam and mux using FFMPEG

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg, webcam

Iam trying to mux audio from two different microphones and video from webcam using ffmpeg in linux.
I used the following code
    `ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -s 320x240 -i /dev/video0 -f alsa -ac 1 -i hw:1,0 -acodec libmp3lame -ab 96k camera.mp4`    
it works for muxing audio from one microphone and video from one webcam
I went through forums and googled for an hour without any positive result.

So, the question is i need to mux two audio from microphones and one video from webcam and produce a video output with two audio tracks.

Thanks

Comment: Add the 2nd input and `-map u`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you give me the complete syntax or any other source as reference.

Comment: Do you know the url for the 2nd mic input?

Comment: @Mulvya the url of second microphone is hw:2,0.

Comment: @shellter thanks for letting me know, i will take necessary steps to move it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -s 320x240 -i /dev/video0 -f alsa -ac 1 -i hw:1,0 -f alsa -ac 1 -i hw:2,0 -map 0 -map 1 -map 2 -acodec libmp3lame -ab 96k camera.mp4
```

Comment: Where is the parameters for the two cameras? I got lost.

Comment: Sorry. *Microhones